# dynamically update webpage photo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firstly, I wanted to say that I am quite new to javascript, thus I would ask you not to criticise me that much.

I wonder, how can I implement the dynamical update of webpage image and it should load a photo from another webpage. I was working with javascript and implemented some functionality, but it is not giving the desired results.

I have searched the Web, but there wasn't anything fitting the above mentioned requirements.

Thus, could anyone please help me figure out the solution to my issue?

```
<script>
        var imageRep = document.createElement('img'), src='http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png';

        var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
        var child=document.getElementById('change').src;
        parent.replaceChild(imageRep,child);

    </script>
```

Here is html part:

```
 <a href="story-ck.html">
            <div class="mix mix-story europe asia" id="div1">
            <img src="img/hero/ck.jpg" style="width: 100%;" id="change">
```

Comment: In short, the image will change depending on your source?

Comment: Another thing, why bother creating another `<img>` if you can just change the `src` attribute?

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the ideal case or in other words it was my dream to make it crawl the images on the certain webpage and with a certain timeout, let's say 20 minutes update the photo on my webpage.

Comment: However you get the new image, you don't need to re-create the `<img>`. Just change the `src` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var imageRep = document.createElement('img');
imageRep.src = 'http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png';
var oldImage = document.getElementById('change');
parent.replaceChild(imageRep, oldImage);
```

Though if you want to do this more than once, and if there's nothing preventing you from doing so, it would be easier to just replace the `.src` of the target image element, rather than replacing the image entirely:

```
document.querySelector('#change').src = 'http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Unfortunately, I am not able to vote up or approve your solution, because I don't have enough points. Another question is can you help make it update the image periodically.

Comment: @SeanKh1 if it solved your issue, you are the asker, so you should be able to accept it: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers -

Answer (score 1):

```js
var change = document.getElementById('change');
function changeImg(){
change.src = 'http://s5.tinypic.com/98yjb6_th.jpg'
}
```

```html
 <img src="http://s6.tinypic.com/id6u77_th.jpg" style="width: 100%;" id="change">" 
 <button onClick='changeImg()'>change image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `src` attribute and set its value to the new image url:

```
var image = document.getElementById('change');
image.src = 'http://www.free.fr/freebox/im/logo_free.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var current=0;
var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('main').src=images[current++%images.length];
},2000);
```

```html
<img src="" id="main">
```

Here's the clear way to handle image rotation.

Answer (score 0):

well you need jquery..

```
$(div).html("<img src='Image name'");
```

this will change your content dynamically by pushing html tags to your page